# How can I reset a particular element without reloading page on clicking button?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am making a rock, paper, scissors game in javascript.It's kind of annoying everytime I have to play and reload the page every single time. So I tried to put a button which resets to a new game. But I am getting error something kind of this: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function.I am sharing my code here.

```js
//Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors

function rpsGame (yourChoice) {
  console.log(yourChoice);
  var humanChoice, botChoice;
  humanChoice = yourChoice.id;

  botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt());
  console.log('Computer choice:', botChoice);

  results = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice);// [0,1] human lost| bot won
  console.log(results)

  message = finalMessage(results); // {message: 'You won!','color: 'green'}
  console.log(message);

  rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice.id, botChoice, message);
  document.getElementById('restart')
}

function randToRpsInt () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function numberToChoice (number) {
  return ["rock", "paper", "scissors"][number];
}

function decideWinner (yourChoice, computerChoice) {
  var rpsDatabase = {
    'rock': { 'scissors': 1, 'rock': 0.5, 'paper': 0 },
    'paper': { 'rock': 1, 'paper': 0.5, 'scissors': 0 },
    'scissors': { 'paper': 1, 'scissors': 0.5, 'rock': 0 }
  }
  var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
  var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice];
  return [yourScore, computerScore];
}

function finalMessage ([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  if (yourScore === 0) {
    return { 'message': 'You lost!', 'color': 'red' };
  } else if (yourScore === 0.5) {
    return { 'message': 'Match tied!', 'color': 'yellow' };
  } else {
    return { 'message': 'You won!', 'color': 'green' };
  }
}

function rpsFrontEnd (humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, finalMessage) {
  var imagesDataBase = {
    'rock': document.getElementById('rock').src,
    'paper': document.getElementById('paper').src,
    'scissors': document.getElementById('scissors').src
  }
  //let's remove all the images
  document.getElementById('rock').remove()
  document.getElementById('paper').remove()
  document.getElementById('scissors').remove()

  var humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var botDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');

  humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[humanImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150 style='box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(37,50,223,1);'>"
  messageDiv.innerHTML = "<h1 style ='color:" + finalMessage['color'] + "; font-size: 60px; padding: 30px; '>" + finalMessage['message'] + "</h1>"
  botDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '" + imagesDataBase[botImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150 style='box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px rgba(243,38,24,1);'>"

  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(humanDiv);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(messageDiv);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(botDiv);

}

function playAgain () {
  document.getElementById("flex-box-rps-div").reset();
}
```

```html
<div class="container-3">
    <h2>Challenge 3: Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-rps">
      <span>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="playAgain()">Restart Game</button>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-box-rps" id="flex-box-rps-div">
      <img id="rock" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rock-clipart-clipart-harvestable-resources-rock.png"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/paper-clipart-nexxuz-Loose-Leaf-Paper.png" height="150"
        width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="scissors"
        src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/muestra-femenina-de-la-victoria-de-la-muestra-de-la-mano-o-signo-de-la-paz-o-tijeras-83128345.jpg"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: `div` elements don't have a reset function - that's what the error is telling you. Only form elements have that (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

Comment: What do you actually mean by "reset" in this context? Presumably you want it to go back to some previous state? If so you need to write specific code to make the specific changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it works to reset the game by clicking anywhere in the element. I'm still trying to figure out how to make a button to reset it but haven't figured that out yet.

```
var rps = document.getElementById('rps');
  rps.addEventListener('mouseup', playAgain);
  function playAgain (){
  location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.reset()` is only a method on a `HTMLFormElement`, you are not using a form element anywhere so you cannot use this method. Try resetting your elements manually.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: I tried with remove function but it is showing an error again.It says like 'index.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null'.Also it remove images.I want it to be like when i click on restart image and text must dissappear and all images must appear.

Answer (score 0):

As said `reset` is only for form elements, what you can instead do to reset to the initial state is as follows:

```
function playAgain () {
    const initialState = `
      <img id="rock" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/rock-clipart-clipart-harvestable-resources-rock.png"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="paper" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/paper-clipart-nexxuz-Loose-Leaf-Paper.png" height="150"
        width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />
      <img id="scissors"
        src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/muestra-femenina-de-la-victoria-de-la-muestra-de-la-mano-o-signo-de-la-paz-o-tijeras-83128345.jpg"
        height="150" width="150" onclick="rpsGame(this)" />`;

    document.getElementById("flex-box-rps-div").innerHTML = initialState;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark this as accepted answer, Thanks